# Real world purpose of sort key in HTML SELECT

Tags: html, web-applications

In web pages we see that a `select` control has value like

```
<option value="in">India</option>
<option value="us">United States</option>
```

what is the purpose of sort key `in` `us` in real world.?

**What is the best practice adopted** while storing these value in DB and while retrieving back? Should we store `India` or `in`?

If we store `in` the problem is somewhere we have to store all mapped country name. right. think about other such kind of selects in your web app we will have to maintain mapped key-value pair for each

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `value` attribute in an `option` element is to specify a machine-processable value corresponding to the option. It can be used as a sort key, but as such it is simply data in the element, and data that gets submitted in the form data.

An obvious use for the attribute is that you can specify standardized, language-neutral values, as opposite to data shown to users. This way, you can e.g. change the language of the page as seen by the user, and still get the same data on the server.

The usual recommendation is that you should internationalize things like references to countries, i.e. use standard codes internally and map them to language-specific names only for presentation to the user. So normally your database should have country codes, not country names.

But there are exceptions. When you need to map codes to names, you will obviously need some data for that. You could use general information like the Common Locale Data Repository ([CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/)), but you might want to have some tunings for them. And you might want to merge such mapping information into your central database, even though it is logically separate from all the rest there.

Comment: So you are saying i should maintain separated mapping of country & country code for different language and only store country code in DB

Comment: @Manish, I’m saying that’s a normal approach, but you can have the mapping in your DB if that’s practical.

Answer (score -1):

you dont get in or us on the server side. POST data contain only India or United States values. in and us are used by select tag to gather data. If you select in you post India to the server if Us than United States

Comment: Just the opposite is true, see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

Comment: hehe i had to be tired answering this question - ofc the opposite is true